# OnCollisionEnter2D not being called

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I'm fairly new to the world of Unity, and am adding collision detection for the first time through RigidBody2D (as this game is 2D). First of all, here is some relevant information:

- **Unity Version:** 4.2.5f
- **Operating System:** Windows 8.1 Update 1

## The Problem

I have two objects that could collide, let's call one `Bullet` and one `Enemy`. Both `Bullet` and `Enemy` have `RigidBody2D` components attached to them, as well as the following method in an attached script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
    print("Hit!");
}
```

However, nothing is printed to the console (I have checked that `print` works in other situations).

## The Question

What is going wrong here? I must be missing something simple. I have checked that Physics 2D has collisions enabled between layers, I have tried the 3D equivalent to this and still no joy.

## Additional Info

[image: Enemy]

[image: Bullet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `BoxCollider2D` component to your `GameObject`s.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html

From the [Unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) for `OnCollisionEnter2D`

> Sent when an incoming collider makes contact with this object's
>   collider

A `Rigidbody2D` just tells a GameObject how to interact with the physics engine. It doesn't provide a collider for collision.

From the [Unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) for `RigidBody2D`

> By adding the appropriate collider component, the sprite will also
>   respond to collisions with other sprites.

Comment: Ah thank you, I must have misread something as I thought RigidBody2D was an alternative rather than supplement! I'll mark this as a solution for now as it makes perfect sense to me, although I'm unable to test at present. Thanks again!

Comment: Confirmed to work (I'd also missed off the script for `Enemy`). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be either:

1. You've not marked your moving rigidbody with the right collision detection method. You need continious dynamic rather than discrete if you are moving your object with speed.
2. Are both rigidbodies marked as kinematic? If so the event won't call.

Comment: 1) There is no `continious dynamic` option, but there is `continious` so I tried that. Sadly it didn't make any difference, and the objects are not travelling so fast that I'd think they'd require it, but it was worth a try!

2) Neither are `kinematic`.

Thank you for your efforts so far :)

Comment: Are either colliders marked as triggers and at the right size? And do the colliders actually collide, i.e does one bounce off the other?

Comment: I cannot see a trigger option anywhere, and they do not bounce off each other either (although once this would be desired behavior when the implementation is feature complete as I'd like both objects to be destroyed)

Comment: Would it help if I posted an image with all the components attached to the object (alongside their settings)? :)

Comment: Yes, that would help :) Also, try decreasing the speed of the bullet. It's possible it's traveling so fast that there is no collision occurring between the objects (are they actually touching?).

Comment: @Neeko I'll post the image shortly, and no the speed is very low and there are multiple update calls whilst they care colliding.

Comment: @Neeko I just added two images that should help :)

Comment: @OMGtechy I see the problem. Posted an answer for you!